# Unexpected results when running script with elevated privileges

Tags: install4j

I'm using install4j 5.1.15.

I have an installer with some custom code added in with the "Custom Code & Resources" tab.  A configurable form sets some properties in an Object from the custom code I added.  I have a RunScript action that writes some files to a directory in the installation tree using information from this Object.  This all works beautifully.

I created a second installer that links to the screens and actions from this installer.  The additional actions are to install a service and start it.  Of course that needs elevated privileges.

I run this new installer and the RunScript fails - no permission to write the files.  Ok so I "elevate to maximum privileges" from the default value for the RunScript action.  I run that installer and I get a Serializable exception - the custom code Object I'm using isn't Serializable.  Ok so I make it Serializable and re-run the installer.  All appears to work as I get no exceptions.

However when I look at the files written it shows that the Object in my custom code does not have the property values that were set by the configurable form.

So I elevated the configurable forms dealing with this Object in hopes of fixing it and it did not.

Can anyone see what I may be missing here?  Thanks in advance for any suggestions anyone may have.

Comment: No enough information to say, Please send your .install4j project file to support@ej-technologies.com and point our the relevant portions

Comment: Ok I ran through things again and it is solved.  In the RunScript I was appending text to a file - because the file was later in a "Replace installer variable" action.  I was not getting an exception but what was failing was writing over the file with the appended text.  It only failed in privileged mode, not if installing as a regular user.  I fixed it by creating the file fully in the RunScript and taking it out of the Replace action.  Thanks for responding to the original question.